# Parse co-ordinates from KML if in 500ft region of a latitude/longitude point

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

I have a KML file (`NewYork.kml`) which has assets listed in co-ordinates (inside `LineStrings`) in the New York region.

I am trying to pick a random point in New York (For example: `40.739974`,`-74.009605`) and get any assets listed within a 500ft range.

I am working with Java/Google Earth API. Does anyone have any tips on which direction to go?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the [geojs](http://code.google.com/p/geojs/) library, in particular the [geo.Point](http://code.google.com/p/geojs/wiki/GeoPointReference) class.

It has useful methods like `distance()` that you could use to see if two coordinates are within 500ft of each other.